# A type trait for std::array

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am trying to define a type trait that I can use with `static_assert` to control that one of my template classes is instantiated only with s`td::array<T,n>`. Here is my attempt:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_std_array : public false_type {};

template <template <typename, size_t> class T, typename V, size_t n>
struct is_std_array<std::array<V, n>> : public true_type {};
```

But I get the following warning from clang:

```
warning: class template partial specialization contains a template parameter
that cannot be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used
non-deductible template parameter 'T'
```

Why is 'T' not deductible? How do I fix that?

Comment: Can you please help me with use of true_type and false_type like this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your syntax on specializing is wrong:

```
template <template <typename, size_t> class T, typename V, size_t n>
```

You're introducing *three* template parameters here: the first of which is a template *template* parameter named `T`, that takes two parameters: a type and a `size_t`. Since `T` is not referenced anywhere in your specialization clause:

```
struct is_std_array<std::array<V, n>> // <== no T
```

it's a non-deduced context. Think of the equivalently written function:

```
template <template <typename, size_t> class T, typename V, size_t n>
void foo(std::array<V, n> );
```

Here, also, `T` is a non-deduced context and so would have to be specified explicitly. However, you don't actually need `T` at all! Just `V` and `n`. What you mean is to simply introduce the two relevant parameters directly:

```
template <typename V, size_t n>
struct is_std_array<std::array<V, n>> : public true_type {};
```

Comment: Looks like this works. I was under the impression that having declared the false version of is_std_array with only T, it would complain about introducing T and n in the true version.

Comment: @Frank You declared the `false` version with a *type* (`T`), and you're specializing on another *type* (`std::array<V, n>`). There are no template templates here.

Comment: Ah - I get it. Thanks a lot!